# npm UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY appears to be wrong

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-install

I'm trying to npm install `simple-react-bootstrap-navbar` into my project.

My project has react 15.1.0 as a dependency.

`simple-react-bootstrap-navbar` has `"react": ">=0.14.0",` as a devDependency.

Yet, when I install, I get this error/warning

[image]

I'm installing `simple-react-bootstrap-navbar` with the --save flag, so react should definitely be a peer dependency satisfying `>=0.14.0`.

So what is causing this error, and how do I fix it?

---

I'm on npm 3.9.3 and Node 4.4.4

Comment: node-gyp is 3.3.1.  The latest npm appears to be 3.9.5, so I don't think I'm too far behind - ditto on Node 4.4.4 - it's not like I'm on an old 0.XX version.  As to no-shrinkwrap, I'm more interested in fixing this for the normal install, since this package will potentially be used by others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a guess but if you look closely, you’ll see the failing peer:

[image]

Even if you somehow managed to install `react@15.1.0`, `react-redux@4.4.0` is explicitly not compatible with it. I’m not sure which version of React you really have but the two packages you have (`simple-react-bootstrap-navbar` and `react-redux@4.4.0`) want different React versions so they conflict.

The solution is simple: install `react-redux@latest` first. [Compatibility with `react@15.x` was added in `react-redux@4.4.1`.](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/releases/tag/v4.4.1)